# Running celery with supervisord unable to discover tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I am using celery 4.1.0 with Django-1.11 and supervisor 3.3.1. For some reason celery is unable to discover the tasks in apps (which are listed in INSTALLED_APPS) when I run celery worker via supervisor. When I run celery from command line it **does** show the tasks. For example, when I run celery from command line here is the output:

Running from command line:

> /home/ubuntu/Env/oba/bin/celery worker -A oba -l DEBUG

```
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://***:**@localhost:***//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . contact.tasks.send_email_to_admin_for_member
  . contact.tasks.send_email_to_admin_for_visitor
```

But when run via supervisord, the output from celery is:

```
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://***:**@localhost:***//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
```

The configuration for supervisord looks something like this:

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/ubuntu/Env/oba/bin/celery -A oba worker -l DEBUG
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/Env/oba/bin"
directory=/home/ubuntu/oba
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/%(program_name)s.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
user=celery
numprocs=1
process_name=%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s
```

Interestingly, when trying to inspect the registered tasks I see:

> home/ubuntu/Env/oba/bin/celery -A oba  inspect registered

```
-> celery@ubuntu-512mb-xxx: OK
    - empty -
```

My celery.py in myproject/oba/celery.py looks something like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oba.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('oba')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

I have declared my task like in contact/tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def send_email_to_admin_for_visitor(contactus_visitor_id):
       pass
```

I am not sure why it is unable to auto discover the tasks. Any clues?

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Any luck in resolving it?

Comment: @Harel No success so far. I am not sure if it is a celery issue or supervisor issue. So still undecided, if I should raise a ticket on supervisor of celery. But I guess doing it in celery might be better. If I get some answers there, I will surely update this ticket.

Comment: I kind agot it to work temporarily by running it in a command line screen session for now, and ensuring all the permissions are more relaxed on the files. This whole thing feels wrong though. I've been using celery for years now, and this is happening on this single project using v4 (was mainly using v3 before).

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.1.0/django/first-steps-with-django.html) of Celery 4.1 is different:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

The difference with your is the lambda function for `app.autodiscover_tasks()`

If that does not fix your problem maybe you need to show how you're declaring your celery tasks.

Comment: I have tried without any arguments for autodiscover_tasks too but still the behaviour is same. I have edited my question to show how I have declared the task.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem previously. And my problem turns out to be the user I used to start the celery worker (here yours is "celery") doesn't have the correct access permission to my app. It means the user can not see the tasks in the app folder.

Check the permission of your app directory and grant the correct permission to your user or use a user already have the permission to your app directory to start the worker should resolve this problem.